# Access session data in codeigniter constant file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am just trying to get the session data in codeigniter `constant` file which is located in `config` folder.

I have been looking around but could find any way to call it.

I also have tried to print all defined variables using following function:

```
$arr = get_defined_vars();
print_r($arr);
```

But, I am unable to see the user data anywhere.

Is there any way I can call session data in constant file ?

Comment: Why you need to access session data in `constants`? Constants never change, and I'm pretty sure that the session data will change depending on user

Comment: Because I have two themes of websites and and would like to show the theme according to user role. Therefore, I have defined the theme constant in constant file.

Comment: Did you try `get_defined_constants()` yet? Although in my opinion, there are better ways of handling themes, such as a theme config file or database table to define them and their properties.

Answer (score 0):

You define in your constant file something like this:
define('TEMPLATE','theme_path');

And You can call in your controller like this:
$this->load->view(TEMPLATE, $data);